# Java List.addAll using collection's stream instead of using collection itself?

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

Recently I found a code snippet which uses stream in List.addAll, but I can't see the reason why it was used.

So given a simple list. `List<E> subList` which is passed as argument to a method. There is a is an other which is a field and contains the same type of elements. `List<E> originalList.`

Here is the the part when the original list is extended with the elements of the sublist.

```
originalList.addAll(subList.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()))
```

What I don't get: why did the author used stream here instead of doing the following:

```
originalList.addAll(subList)
```

Is there a benefit of using streams in this situation?

Comment: The stream version will warm the data centre more than the non-stream version.

Comment: Honestly I found it weird, but as I'm not familiar with streams yet I didn't want to judge anybody. :)

Comment: I would ask the author.  To me it smells of somebody experimenting with a new approach rather than there being any advantage to it.  It is easier to list disadvantages ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference at all, using `originalList.addAll(subList)` will do exactly the same because `addAll()` method creates an array copy of `subList` in memory and does not point to the same reference. Perhaps there was some intermediate operation in the `Stream` which was cleared and author forgot to clean-up the code.

Use `originalList.addAll(subList)` as there is no need to create a stream and collect it to `List`, it's just unnecessary operations.

Answer (score 2):

Thing is: **streams**, together with "good lambdas" **can** be have better performance than "old school" looping approaches. But this heavily depends on your context (see [here](https://jaxenter.com/java-performance-tutorial-how-fast-are-the-java-8-streams-118830.html) for an extensive discussion of this subject).

And of course, the **real** performance kick of streams comes into play when you have some *stream()* based operation; and by just changing that into *parallelStream()* you start doing things in parallel. But (also of course): you still need to know what you are doing! Not everything can be made "parallel" that easy.

Talking about the example you are showing: no benefits in using streams there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for the article.